# Plotting with lines connecting points

Tags: python, plot

I'm creating a program to determine a minimum, maximum, and percentiles of winds at certain heights.  The file is split into 5 columns.  My code thus far looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = open('wind.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    z = columns[0]
    u_min = columns[1]
    u_10 = columns[2]
    u_max = columns[4]
    u_90 = columns[3]

    plt.plot(u_min,z,'-o')
    plt.plot(u_max,z,'-o')
```

[image: This shows the max and mins of the wind]plt.show()

As you can see it's plotting each min and max at the specific altitude with just a dot.  How can I adjust that so it makes it a line instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*edited answer due to comment*

To create a line that connects all min values:

1. Store all min values in a list (using append)
2. Plot the list

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = open('wind.txt', 'r')
min_vector = []
max_vector = []
z_vector = []
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    z = columns[0]
    u_min = columns[1]
    u_10 = columns[2]
    u_max = columns[4]
    u_90 = columns[3]

    min_vector.append(u_min)
    max_vector.append(u_max)
    z_vector.append(z)

plt.plot(min_vector, z_vector, '-o')
plt.plot(max_vector, z_vector, '-o')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm actually trying to connect the dots between just the minimum section and then just the maximum section.  That connects the bottom minimum dot to the bottom maximum dot

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a single line from the top to the bottom of the left scatter, you can do like so:

```
plot([u_min[0], u_min[-1], [z[0], z[-1], color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
```